# HEVC format convert to MP4 in ubuntu

Tags: mp4, handbrake, hevc

I have some videos in HEVC x265 format. My usual media players don't support this format. when I go for a quick search I get `HandBrake` software for converting this kind of format.

Do you have any cool software of any idea for converting or play such video files without lag or fading gray color on picture.

Comment: What made Handbrake unsuitable?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `avconv` for converting audio/video files

```
avconv -i your_x265file -qscale 1 -c:v libx264 -c:a copy output_x264file.mp4
```

*Explanation:*

```
-qscale 1 - range from 1 to 31 where 1 is the best quality
-c:v - codec video convert to x264
-c:a - codec audio copy as is
```

You can check what encoders are present with `avconv -encoders` and you can use something different from x264

You have to be prepared it can take a long time according to your hardware

Comment: This answer still (almost) works on Ubuntu 20.04! As there's no `avconv`, you can just substitute it with `ffmpeg` using the exact same options, and it works. Same holds true for `ffmpeg -encoders`.